# Close BottomDrawer in Android by tapping on the empty portion of the screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When `BottomDrawer` is opened, it will cover half of the screen. How to let the user click on the other half that is not covered to close `BottomDrawer`

```kotlin
BottomDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        gesturesEnabled = false,
        drawerContent = {
            LazyColumn {
                ...
            }
        }
    ){
        LazyColumn {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Gestures need to be enabled through `gesturesEnabled = true`

Comment: This does exactly what needs to be done on click on whitespace to close. But the reason why I set `gesturesEnabled = false` is that the components near the bottom of the screen can be scrolled, such as `LazyColumn`, which will cause gesture conflicts when swiping from bottom to top. `LazyColumn` will not be scrollable.